# How to concatenate text fields into one field?

Tags: sql, sqlite

My table has 3 text fields: open_time_2, close_time_2, displayed_value (sample values are '5:45', '4:15', '').
Need to update displayed_value with text '4:15 - 5:45'.
If I use the following query:

```
UPDATE mytable SET displayed_value=(close_time_2 + '-' open_time_2) 
WHERE close_time_2!=""
```

In result I am getting value '9.0'. What is wrong here?

Comment: what is the datatype of targetColumn??

Comment: displayed_value is TEXT also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the SQLite concatenation operator, `||`, rather than addition:

```
UPDATE mytable SET displayed_value=(close_time_2 || '-' || open_time_2)
WHERE close_time_2 != ""
```

Comment: Thanks. Strange that documentation says that + can be used with strings.

Comment: + can be used for strings, but is still the addition operator - it will attempt to convert the strings to numbers (`'2'` gets converted to `2`, `'3abcd'` gets converted to `3`, `'abcd'` gets converted to `0`, and, as in your case, `'4:15'` gets converted to `4`, hence the result of `9`)